# Emptying a database table with multiple concurrent processes

Tags: java, database

I have multiple processes that should all take one record from a table, process it and remove it when it's processed. All the records from the table need to be processed this way.

What is the best way to make sure that all the processes take a different record and that no records are skipped (without creating a single point of failure)?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sounds like you want a queue of tasks to be assigned to the next available consumer.

Comment: Actually I don't the DBMS I'm going to use right now, but chances are it's going to be DB2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've done this in the past is to add "status" and "worked_id" columns to the table you're processing. A record would go from status "un-processed" to "processing" to "done".

Each thread then starts its work along the following lines:

```
update table 
set    status = processing, 
       worker_id = <<my thread ID>>
where  status is null
and    <<some way to select the rows you want to process>>
```

The thread processes the row; then once it's done:

```
delete from table
where  status = processing
and    worker_id = <<my thread ID>>
and    <<some way to select the rows you just processed>>
```

By storing the status in the database, you can create a sanity check - for instance, when the application starts and ends, you should have no rows in status "processing". If the application crashes, you can find the rows that were affected. You can then decide what to do - you may need to tidy up the output - but by marking it as "not processed", you can re-run the process.

If you wrap the statements in transactions (you probably do more complicated logic than this sample) you can guarantee atomicity.

Comment: Would this work if the update is not commited? Because if any of the process crash this need to be rollbacked so that the record can be taken by another process.

Answer (score 1):

Use producer-consumer pattern.

Use single thread to `SELECT` rows from db for processing and distribute it to N worker threads that will do actuall processing. Assuming that only workers have access to processed row, they can perform `DELETE` as well.

Comment: Thanks, I though about this, but this would create a single point of failure. Which is something I really need to avoid. Also, it would be independent processes not java threads. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Threads or processes it doesnt matter. Either way you need some sort of synchronization that will be single point of failure.